# How to fix Android Spinner selection if it is not working?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

Android Spinner is not working, the API is working and the Spinner's list of items is working. However, the item selection is not working.

```
class PlayerSignup2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var positions : List<Position>

    val positionSpinner = positionsSpinner

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(com.example.app.R.layout.activity_user_signup2)

        //Positions from API
        positions = APIService.getPositions(this)

        val spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, positions)
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item)
        positionSpinner.adapter = spinnerAdapter

    }
```

Spinner list
[image: Spinner List]

After selecting any item

[image: After selecting an item from the list]

Any idea on how to fix this?!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the item selection is not working"? That is, what are you expecting to happen when you select an item?

Comment: What do mean by not working? and share on selection code

Comment: When I select an item, the selection does not show. Also, the selected item returns '-1'

Comment: @MikeM. I've added screenshots, please take a look at them and up-vote the question, as someone down-voted it.

Comment: @AhmedElgameel, `implements  
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` and you will get `onItemSelected` will work for you

Comment: Please make sure that you don't have set font color white, and also there is a need to handle AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener as @RakeshKumar told.

Comment: @ParthPatel, without that method how he will get the data whatever position he has clicked?

Comment: @RakeshKumar Please check below answer given by Muhaiminur Rahman, has added a comment to get selected item by position

Comment: @ParthPatel, That's what I was meant to say and exactly saying like that

Comment: Like @Parth said and/or not enough width

Answer (score 0):

try using `prompt` for adding title in .`XML` file

```
<Spinner
          android:id="@+id/spinner"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>
```

or try adding 1 more item that contains whatever title you want like "select position" on index 0.

```
positions.add("select position");
positions.add("value 1");
```

after adding values to list set spinner value to index 0 by default using below code. 
`mSpinner.setSelection(0)`  .

and on `Item Selected` check if index 0 or value is "select position" then ignore selection else perform action you want.

```
 private lateinit var positions : List<Position>


        //add dummy data first
        positions.add(Position("select position"));

        //Positions from API
        positions.addAll(APIService.getPositions(this));
```

Comment: `positions` list is retrieved via API call. As you can see in the screenshots, I think there is no problem with the Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In Kotlin

```
class MainActivity : /** Other Classes, */AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

var list_of_items = arrayOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    spinner!!.setOnItemSelectedListener(this)

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using a simple spinner layout and languages array
    val aa = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_of_items)
    // Set layout to use when the list of choices appear
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    // Set Adapter to Spinner
    spinner!!.setAdapter(aa)
}

override fun onItemSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>, arg1: View, position: Int, id:Long{
    // use position to know the selected item
    //here you will get the answwer
}

override fun onNothingSelected(arg0: AdapterView<*>) {

}
}
```